# Javascript regex to extract all characters between quotation marks following a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have the text:

```
s.events="event3"
s.pageName="Forum: Index"
s.channel="forum"
s.prop1="Forum: Index"
s.prop2="Index Page"
s.prop36=""
s.prop37=""
s.prop38=""
s.prop39=""
s.prop40="53"
s.prop41="Anonymous"
s.prop42="username"
s.prop43=""
s.prop47=""
s.eVar1="Forum: Index"
s.eVar2="Index Page"
s.eVar36=""
s.eVar37=""
```

saved in a var in javascript and I want to extract the text between the quotes of s.prop42 giving me the result:

```
"username"
```

what I have right now is

```
    var regex = /\?prop.42="([^']+)"/;
    var test = data.match(regex);
```

but it doesnt seem to work, can someone help me out?

Comment: Why are you trying to match a literal question mark? Why are you not allowing *single* quotes in a *double*-quote terminated string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var myregex = /s\.prop42="([^"]*)"/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[1];
}
```

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS8mF0/5), look at the capture group **in the right pane**.

**Explanation**

- `s\.prop42="` matches `s.prop42="` (but we won't retrieve it)
- The parentheses in `([^"]*)` capture any chars that are not a `"`  to Group 1: this is what we want
- The code gets the Group 1 capture

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the green checkmark! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on above answer, but I think the regex is better with .* like so:

```
var myregex = /s\.prop42="(.*)"/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[1];
}
```